# DotNetZip ExtractAll Zip64

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I create a zip File using "UseZip64WhenSaving" option as true.
Once I try to extract it with "ExtractAll" method, an exception is thrown saying that the file "nameOfMyFile.z65536" does not exist. 
It does not happen with files created as normal zip (not zip64). 
Any suggestion to solve the issue?

The code creating the file:

```
using (ZipFile zCompressor = new ZipFile(strNameOftheZipFile))
 {
     zCompressor.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.Always;
    FileInfo[] fiArrayFiles = dInfoBCP.GetFiles("*.bcp", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (FileInfo fileTemp in fiArrayFiles)
    {
        zCompressor.AddFile(fileTemp.FullName);
    }
     zCompressor.MaxOutputSegmentSize = (700 * 984540);
     zCompressor.Save();
 }
```

The code to extract (that generates the error):

```
ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(FullNameOfmyZipFile);
zip.ExtractAll(strPathDest, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
```

Comment: Did you verify the file actually exist?

Comment: Yes, it exists. The "Read" method correctly retrieve the file I want to extract. Then the ExtractAll method looks for the file with "z65536" extension.

Comment: but does the `nameOfMyFile.z65536` exist?

Comment: No it does not exist.

Comment: I just made a test compressing and extracting with older version of DotNetZip (1.13.5) and it works correctly. So it seems to be an issue introduced with latest version (1.13.6)

Comment:  I suggest you open a bug report there

Comment: Yes, I'll do. Thanks